# Cocos2dx - Touch not recognized on Android

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, touch

I'm having trouble with a touch listener not picking up touch events on android, but doing fine in windows (mouse input). I've got a Node listening for touches (not a Layer), but from what I've been seeing around it seems having it on a Layer isn't a requirement anymore?

**Setup**

```
void DodgePlayerController::setupPlayerInput()
{
    CCLOG("DodgePlayerController::setupPlayerInput()");
    if (myPawn)
    {
        Pellet* myPellet = dynamic_cast<Pellet*>(myPawn);
        if (myPellet)
        {
            CCLOG("DodgePlayerController::setupPlayerInput() !!2!!");
            //setup the player input and events (should build some sort of player controller)
            auto listener = EventListenerTouchAllAtOnce::create();
            listener->onTouchesBegan = CC_CALLBACK_2(Pellet::setTargetPosition, myPellet);
            listener->onTouchesMoved = CC_CALLBACK_2(Pellet::setTargetPosition, myPellet);
            listener->onTouchesEnded = CC_CALLBACK_2(Pellet::clearTargetPosition, myPellet);
            listener->onTouchesCancelled = CC_CALLBACK_2(Pellet::clearTargetPosition, myPellet);

            auto dispatcher = getEventDispatcher();
            dispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(listener, this);
        }
    }
}
```

When logging on Android, I'm getting through both CCLOG messages correctly (I have a 'disablePlayerInput()' which isn't being called, so the listener shouldn't be removed). This all works fine in the windows application, but when I load it in Android the touches aren't picked up (Pellet::setTargetPosition also has a log message which doesn't get thrown in android).

Anyone know what I might be missing?

Answer (score -1):

Try to add 
*setSwallowTouches (true);*
after creating the listener.

Comment: This answer would be improved by explaining to the asker what this function does and why it would solve the described problem.